# How do I get image to display when tapping various markers taken by camera intent?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am trying to display a full size image of the marker (thumbnail) of the image taken by the camera intent on that point the users has tapped.  But so far the image is displayed but always show the latest image taken and not the one taken before when tapping on the first marker.

Here is my code so far:

```
public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {
      poinOnMap=point;

      googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                                   selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String fileUri = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri);
                Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + bitmap + fileUri);
                intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            return;
          }
      });
     getApplicationContext().getDir(
              getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);

          fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                  "/" +getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)),new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"));
          Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
          startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,TAKE_PICTURE);
  }

       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                  try {
                      GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                      bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e1) {
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                  }
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Uri selectedImage is null

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
```